# Validating Duplicate Data Between ObservableArrays

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have an observable array (populated via ajax) that on validation, cannot have a select value the same on any 2 or more observables within the array.

```
<div id="AttrValidationDiv"></div>
    <table>    
    <!-- ko foreach: AttrsViewModels -->
         <tr>
            <td>
              <select data-bind="options:$root.optionsViewModel, optionsText:'ProductName', optionsValue:'ProductId',value:ServiceGroup, optionsCaption:'Select'"></select>
           </td>
          </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </table>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in adding/removing from the validation div in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a computed function that checks each option against the selected options in your AttrsViewModels. The computed will automatically recalculate whenever a selected option changes because they're observables, and the div text will be updated if bound to the computed function.

```js
function viewModel(){
  var self = this;
  
  this.optionsViewModel = [
    { ProductId: 1, ProductName: 'product 1' },
    { ProductId: 2, ProductName: 'product 2' },
    { ProductId: 3, ProductName: 'product 3' }
  ];
  
  this.AttrsViewModels = ko.observableArray([
    { ServiceGroup: ko.observable() },
    { ServiceGroup: ko.observable() },
    { ServiceGroup: ko.observable() }
  ]);
  
  this.validations = ko.computed(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<self.optionsViewModel.length; i++){
     var option = self.optionsViewModel[i];
        var matches = self.AttrsViewModels().filter(function(item){
            return item.ServiceGroup() === option.ProductId;
        });
        if(matches.length >= 2){
           return option.ProductName + ' is selected more than once';
        }
    }
    return '';
  });
}
    
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="AttrValidationDiv">
  <span data-bind="text: validations"></span>
</div>
<table>    
    <tbody>
    <!--ko foreach: AttrsViewModels-->
     <tr>
        <td>
          <select data-bind="options:$root.optionsViewModel, optionsText:'ProductName', optionsValue:'ProductId',value:ServiceGroup, optionsCaption:'Select'"></select>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <!--/ko-->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to pull in a "Level" property within the AttrsViewModels.  Ex: "'The Service Group in Level 1 is already selected for Level(s) 2,3."

Comment: @Mildfire I'm not sure what your structure looks like but I don't see why not. If you can put together a jsFiddle with more of your code included I'll take a look.

Comment: I got it.  Accessed it through match array.